# Can pseudo selectors (such as :hover) be used with the universal selector?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to develop some components that hide themselves unless their parent div is in a hover state. I try to keep my CSS untied to my HTML structure, so I structured my rule like this:

```
.show-on-hover
{
  display:none;
}
*:hover > .show-on-hover
{
  display:block;
}
```

I recognize browsers choke on the universal selector at times, and this is the case here. The code works when inside an iFrame (like JSBin), or if I change `*:hover` to `p:hover`. However, Chrome refuses to acknowledge the rule on a normal environment.

You can see my code here, but you need to get it out of JSBin and into a file to really see what's going on.

http://jsbin.com/tukeqeco/2/edit

This might sound like a dumb question, and maybe I'm just not seeing something here, but is this part of the spec? If so, where, and why isn't this more well documented? Why does it work in an iframe, but not in a regular part of the browser?

Edit:

I went and changed my code to this:

```
:not(fakeTag):hover > .show-on-hover
{ 
  display:block;
}
```

It does exactly what I wanted `*:hover > .show-on-hover` to do. If there is a limitation in the spec on the `*` selector or the `>` selector, why is it there, since I'm able to do silly things like this to get around it?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me (Mac). It's perfectly legal, so far as I know.

Comment: Did you just try the JSBin? Because the JSBin will decieve you. Try it using an actual file, and see if you can duplicate the error. I am also using Chrome on a Mac. The error also occurs on Firefox.

Comment: If the jsbin can "deceive you", *why* is it provided as a supporting test-case?

Comment: It isn't illegal, it's just redundant.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? What is redundant?

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you, I'll remove the JSBin link from the question and post it here in this comment. It was really just for convenience of posting the required HTML for the error duplication.

Comment: @BryanRayner A supporting test-case really *is* needed here, but it should not be a "deceptive" one!

Comment: @Adrift, that's what I thought as well. But it seems that Chrome (at least on my machine) doesn't support this unless it's in an iFrame.

Comment: `Did you just try the JSBin?` No, I pasted the code into an HTML file and ran it in Chrome. No probs at all.

Comment: See the answer for my stupidity. Thanks everyone, sometimes you never find a problem until you try explaing it to someone else.

Answer (score 5):

I feel really stupid now :)

The problem is solved by changing

```
<!doctype>
```

to

```
<!doctype html>
```

Strange that I didn't notice that until now. How many sites have I developed just using  and not realizing that it was invalid?